# Symfony 4 / angular 8 : read nested JSON and fill object with its content

Tags: json, angular, symfony, request, response

I'm trying to send a post http request from angular side to symfony server to signup a user, my user object contain a second object which is address, json object look like that :

```
{
  "user": {
    "firstname": "b",
    "last name": "d",
    "email": "f",
    "password": "f",
    "civility": "f",
    "phone": "f",
    "Address": {
      "city":"rr",
      "country":"rr",
      "postalcode":"77"
    }

  }
}
```

I'm sending request on the front side from my service with :

```
export class RegisterService {
  user: User;
  address: Address;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  registerUser(civility: string, firstname: string, lastname: string, tel: string, street: string, city: string, country: string, postalcode: number, email: string, password: string, ): Promise<any> {
    this.user = new User();
    this.address = new Address()

    this.user.username = email;
    this.user.civility = civility;
    this.user.firstname = firstname;
    this.user.lastname = lastname;
    this.user.tel = tel;
    this.user.email = email;
    this.user.password = password;

    this.address.street = street;
    this.address.city = city;
    this.address.country = country;
    this.address.postalcode = postalcode;

    this.user.address = this.address;
    console.log(this.user);
    return this.http.post((`${config.apiUrl}/api/auth/register`), this.user).toPromise();
  }
}
```

and here what I'm doing on symfony part :

```
/**
     * @Route("/register", name="api_auth_register",  methods={"POST"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @param UserManagerInterface $userManager
     * @return JsonResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function register(Request $request, UserManagerInterface $userManager)
    {
        $data = json_decode(
            $request->getContent(),
            true
        );
        $validator = Validation::createValidator();
        $constraint = new Assert\Collection(array(
            'username' => new Assert\Type("string"),
            'password' => new Assert\Length(array('min' => 6)),
            'email' => new Assert\Email(),
            'firstname' => new Assert\Type("string"),
            'lastname' => new Assert\Type("string"),
            'tel' => new Assert\Type("string"),
            'civility' => new Assert\Type("string"),
            'city' => new Assert\Type("string"),
            'country' => new Assert\Type("string"),
            'street' => new Assert\Type("string"),
            'postalcode' => new Assert\Type("string"),

        ));
        $violations = $validator->validate($data, $constraint);
        if ($violations->count() > 0) {
            return new JsonResponse(["error" => (string) $violations], 500);
        }

        $user = new User();
        $address = new Adress();


        var_dump($data);

        $user->setPlainPassword($data['password']);
        $user->setEmail($data['email']);
        $user->setEnabled(true);
        $user->setRoles(['ROLE_USER']);
        $user->setSuperAdmin(false);
        $user->setLastname($request->get('lastname'));
        $user->setFirstname($request->get('firstname'));
        $user->setTel($request->get('tel'));
        $user->setCivility($request->get('civility'));


        $address->setCity($request->get('city'));
        $address->setCountry($request->get('country'));
        $address->setStreet($request->get('street'));
        $address->setPostalCode($request->get('postalcode'));
        $user->setAddress($address);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($address);
        $em->flush();

        try {
            $userManager->updateUser($user, true);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return new JsonResponse(["error" => $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }
        return new JsonResponse(["success" . " has been registered!"], 200);
```

I'm getting a 500 server error (Internal Server Error) which is  :

> error: "Array[city]:↵    This field is missing. (code
>   2fa2158c-2a7f-484b-98aa-975522539ff8)↵Array[country]:↵    This field
>   is missing. (code
>   2fa2158c-2a7f-484b-98aa-975522539ff8)↵Array[street]:↵    This field is
>   missing. (code
>   2fa2158c-2a7f-484b-98aa-975522539ff8)↵Array[postalcode]:↵    This
>   field is missing. (code
>   2fa2158c-2a7f-484b-98aa-975522539ff8)↵Array[address]:↵    This field
>   was not expected. (code 7703c766-b5d5-4cef-ace7-ae0dd82304e9)↵"

some help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, since your sent object contains the address as a sub structure, that your `Assert\Collection` should have an `address` key, to mimic the expected format:

```
    $constraint = new Assert\Collection(array(
        'username' => new Assert\Type("string"),
        'password' => new Assert\Length(array('min' => 6)),
        'email' => new Assert\Email(),
        'firstname' => new Assert\Type("string"),
        'lastname' => new Assert\Type("string"),
        'tel' => new Assert\Type("string"),
        'civility' => new Assert\Type("string"),
        'address' => new Assert\Collection(array(
          'city' => new Assert\Type("string"),
          'country' => new Assert\Type("string"),
          'street' => new Assert\Type("string"),
          'postalcode' => new Assert\Type("string"),
        )),
    ));
```